# Использование "using" для закрытия соединения

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(constr))
{
   ...
}
```

Вызванный в конце метод Dispose() только удалит объект "connection" из памяти? В таком случае нужно закрывать соединение (connection.Close()) самому?

Comment: нет и нет *(3 символа нужно...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала об удалении объекта из памяти. В .NET объект (ссылочного типа) может быть удалён из памяти только сборщиком мусора. Конструкция `using`, так же как и метод `Dispose`, который она вызывает, не удаляет объект из памяти.

Метод `Dispose`, как это и принято, [вызывает `Close`](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/npgsql/npgsql/test/EntityFramework6.Npgsql.Tests/..%5C..%5Csrc%5CNpgsql%5CNpgsqlConnection.cs) (пролистайте вниз до метода `Dispose`). Поэтому соединение будет закрыто, вызывать `Close` самостоятельно в вашем случае дополнительно не нужно.

Answer (score 4):

Dispose из памяти ничего не удаляет, этот метод нужен для освобождения системных ресурсов (сокетов, дескрипторов и т.д). В Вашем случае он должен вызвать Close для вашего соединения. Следовательно, дополнительно делать ничего не нужно.